# How can I Add/Remove Classes to Menu Items whilst scrolling with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a website whereby it's made up of individual section elements which have IDs laid out like the below (it has more HTML than below but I've trimmed it down for simplicity):

```
<section id="home">
    First Section
</section>
<section id="about_us">
    Second Section
</section>
<section id="what_we_do">
    Third Section
</section>
<section id="the_process">
    Fourth Section
</section>
<section id="contact">
    Fifth Section
</section>
```

I also have a menu like this where the li tags have classes with the corresponding text sections above:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="navbar-nav">
    <li itemscope="itemscope" id="menu-item-79" class="home menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item menu-item-79"><a title="Home" href="#home" class="nav-link current_section">Home</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" id="menu-item-75" class="about_us menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item menu-item-75"><a title="About Us" href="#about_us" class="nav-link current_section">About Us</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" id="menu-item-84" class="what_we_do menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item menu-item-84"><a title="What We Do" href="#what_we_do" class="nav-link">What We Do</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" id="menu-item-81" class="the_process menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item menu-item-81"><a title="The Process" href="#the_process" class="nav-link">The Process</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" id="menu-item-82" class="contact menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom nav-item menu-item-82"><a title="Contact" href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I then have some jQuery which detects whether the section is in the viewport, if it is it adds a class, if it isn't it removes the class like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('section').each(function() {
        var top_of_element = $(this).offset().top;
        var bottom_of_element = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
        var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if ((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)){
            $('.sticky_menu li.'+ id +' a').addClass('current_section');
        } else {
            $('.sticky_menu li.'+ id +' a').removeClass('current_section');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that two menu items always highlight as I scroll down the page. What I need it to do is once you scroll down and start a new section the corresponding menu item highlights.

Any help would be appreciate, I believe what I have is close but needs a tweak and needs to be simplified.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(top_of_screen >= top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)
```

Comment: Please add some more information to your answer. Use the **edit** function to modify your answer and explain how you solved the issue and what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see where you are going with this: A scrollable container and highlight the links for the in-view sections.

Here I used a grid with a stickily header (per one comment observed) and used that as the scrollable container.  Some CSS just to show a scrollable container visually.

- When items are visible in the Y axis we want to highlight the linked associated with that.
- Dealt with a window resize also by triggering the scroll.
- Avoided challenges with the attached class but triggering a scroll event on startup on our container
- Credit where due; borrowed some code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21627295/125981 with some leverage of jQuery but could be done in vanilla JavaScript also on the events.

```js
var visibleY = function(el) {
  let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    top = rect.top,
    height = rect.height;
  el = el.parentNode;
  // Check if bottom of the element not in scrollable area
  if (rect.bottom < 0) return false;
  // Check its within the document viewport
  if (top > document.documentElement.clientHeight) return false;
  do {
    rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
    if (top <= rect.bottom === false) return false;
    // Check if the element is out of view due to a container scrolling
    if ((top + height) <= rect.top) return false;
    el = el.parentNode;
  } while (el != document.body)
  return true;
};

var update = function($el) {
  let isVisible = visibleY($el[0]);
  let targM = $el.data('menu');
  $('#menu-main-menu').find(targM)
    .toggleClass('current_section', isVisible);
};

$(window).on('resize', function(event) {
  $('main').trigger('scroll');
});
$('main').on('scroll', function(event) {
  let $main = $(this);
  $('#menu-main-menu')
    .find('.nav-link').toggleClass('current_section', false);
  $main.find('section').each(function() {
    let $section = $(this);
    update($section);
  });
}).trigger('scroll');
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0; /* prevents scrollbars */
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.all-page {
  /* container for our page with a scollable main block and sticky header */
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'header' 'main';
}

.navbar-nav {
  grid-area: header;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 3em;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FF000020;
  border-bottom: 1px red solid;
}

main {
  /* scrollable container to work with */
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
}

section {
  /* just some style to illustrate the scroll */
  height: 6em;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background-color: #00FF0020;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

section:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.current_section {
  background-color: #0000FF20;
}

footer {
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFF0020;
  border: solid 3px #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all-page">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="navbar-nav">
    <li itemscope="itemscope" class="home menu-item nav-item "><a title="Home" href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" class="about_us menu-item nav-item "><a title="About Us" href="#about_us" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" class="what_we_do menu-item nav-item "><a title="What We Do" href="#what_we_do" class="nav-link">What We Do</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" class="the_process menu-item nav-item "><a title="The Process" href="#the_process" class="nav-link">The Process</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" class="contact menu-item nav-item"><a title="Contact" href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <main>
    <section id="home" data-menu=".home .nav-link">
      First Section Homer
    </section>
    <section id="about_us" data-menu=".about_us .nav-link">
      Second Section Abouter
    </section>
    <section id="what_we_do" data-menu=".what_we_do .nav-link">
      Third Section WeDO
    </section>
    <section id="the_process" data-menu=".the_process .nav-link">
      Fourth Section Proc
    </section>
    <section id="contact" data-menu=".contact .nav-link">
      Fifth Section Contact!
    </section>
    <footer>I am a footer</footer>
  </main>
</div>
```